# i18next.init() does not complete when using i18next-resources-to-backend with lazy load to FileReader

Tags: i18next

I seem to have a strange issue, where the 'ready' callback is not triggering when using resourcesToBackend in lazy load mode.

My code runs as follows and the language files are available on the path.
console.log also reports that the language / namespace dictionaries have loaded.

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import i18nextSprintfPostProcessor from 'i18next-sprintf-postprocessor';
import i18nextResourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend'

i18next.use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector).use(i18nextResourcesToBackend((language, namespace)=>{
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         MyFsReadFile(`i18n/${language}/${namespace}.json`, (file)=>{
           const reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = (ev)=>{ resolve(JSON.parse(ev.target.result)) };
           reader.readAsText(file);
         }), (error)=>{
           if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') console.log('i18nextResourcesToBackend error', language, namespace, error);
           reject(error);
         }
      });
    })).use(i18nextSprintfPostProcessor)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    ns: ['app','test','core'], defaultNS: 'app', fallbackNS: 'core',
    overloadTranslationOptionHandler: i18nextSprintfPostProcessor.overloadTranslationOptionHandler
  }, (err, t)=> {

// this is never called ..!    
  });
```

The strange thing is that the use of this configuration using the standard i18next-http-backend plugin, it works correctly (and has done for years - thank you very much).

The language / namespace files all exist and correctly loaded and parsed as JSON.

Is there something else that is needed to trigger when the dictionaries have been loaded?

Thank you.

The 'success' callback on init() should be called.

Comment: how does your debug output look like?

Comment: what is the result of JSON.parse(ev.target.result) ?

Comment: is i18next-resources-to-backend up-to-date?

Comment: @adrai - thank you for your very fast response.

I added some console.log() statements to generate the output you requested, and the strangest thing ... it works!

I think it might have something to do with detecting the language from the configuration - this App is packaged with Cordova, and it seems that i18next-browser-languagedetector may be mis-firing. However, it is / was working when using the http-backend.

I added a changeLanguage call, which this seems to fix the issue

```
      i18next.changeLanguage(navigator.language || 'en');
```

Thank you for looking at this.